# Pattern for global data in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Hi I'm working on an Sf2 project, and I re-use an array with U.S. state postal codes throughout the application-- in controllers, validation, and form classes.   What's the best place to stash this and similar "global" data so that I keep it in one place?  I was thinking about extending the Base Controller class and putting it there but thought I'd see what the community thought.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For US State Postal Codes, I'd create a custom FormType, that lives in, for example `Acme\YourBundle\Form\UsPostalCodeType`, which can be used to create a dropdown box with Symfony's FormBuilder.

I have one that I use for a list of Counties in England.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\SomethingBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class EnglandCountyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices' => self::getCounties()
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'england_county';
    }

    /**
     * A custom method to apply the values of the array as the keys also and return that array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getCounties()
    {
        $choices = array(
            "Greater London",
            "West Midlands",
            "Greater Manchester",
            "West Yorkshire",
            "Kent",
            "Essex",
            "Merseyside",
            "South Yorkshire",
            "Hampshire",
            "Lancashire",
            "Surrey",
            "Hertfordshire",
            "Tyne and Wear",
            "Norfolk",
            "Staffordshire",
            "West Sussex",
            "Nottinghamshire",
            "Derbyshire",
            "Devon",
            "Suffolk",
            "Lincolnshire",
            "Northamptonshire",
            "Oxfordshire",
            "Leicestershire",
            "Cambridgeshire",
            "North Yorkshire",
            "Gloucestershire",
            "Worcestershire",
            "Warwickshire",
            "Cornwall",
            "Somerset",
            "East Sussex",
            "County Durham",
            "Buckinghamshire",
            "Cumbria",
            "Wiltshire",
            "Bristol",
            "Dorset",
            "Cheshire East",
            "East Riding of Yorkshire",
            "Leicester",
            "Cheshire West and Chester",
            "Northumberland",
            "Shropshire",
            "Nottingham",
            "Brighton & Hove",
            "Medway",
            "South Gloucestershire",
            "Plymouth",
            "Hull",
            "Central Bedfordshire",
            "Milton Keynes",
            "Derby",
            "Stoke-on-Trent",
            "Southampton",
            "Swindon",
            "Portsmouth",
            "Luton",
            "North Somerset",
            "Warrington",
            "York",
            "Stockton-on-Tees",
            "Peterborough",
            "Herefordshire",
            "Bournemouth",
            "Bath and North East Somerset",
            "Southend-on-Sea",
            "North Lincolnshire",
            "Telford and Wrekin",
            "North East Lincolnshire",
            "Thurrock",
            "Bedford",
            "Reading",
            "Wokingham",
            "West Berkshire",
            "Poole",
            "Blackburn with Darwen",
            "Windsor and Maidenhead",
            "Blackpool",
            "Slough",
            "Middlesbrough",
            "Isle of Wight",
            "Redcar and Cleveland",
            "Torbay",
            "Halton",
            "Bracknell Forest",
            "Darlington",
            "Hartlepool",
            "Rutland",
            "Isles of Scilly",
        );

        asort($choices);

        return array_combine($choices, $choices);
    }
}
```

To validate against it, you can call the static method that returns the array of choices as a callback

```
# src/Acme/SomethingBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\SomethingBundle\Entity\Person:
    properties:
        county:
            - Choice: { callback: [\Acme\SomethingBundle\Form\EnglandCountyType, getCounties] }
```

or if using annotations in your entity

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

//....

/**
 * @Assert\Choice(callback={"\Acme\SomethingBundle\Form\EnglandCountyType","getCounties"})
 */
protected $county;
```

If you were using this with validation groups, this would become

```
/**
 * @Assert\Choice(callback={"\Acme\SomethingBundle\Form\EnglandCountyType","getCounties"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"group1"})
 */
protected $county;
```

If you wanted to use it in your controller with for example, a foreach loop

```
use Acme\SomethingBundle\Form\EnglandCountyType;

$counties = EnglandCountyType::getCounties();
foreach ($counties as $county) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  The problem is that I also use the list for validation groups and also with "for" loops in various controllers.

Comment: @Acyra Sure, that can be done, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#supplying-the-choices-with-a-callback-function). I've update my answer to provide an example of this

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a service for it, which you can inject to whatever needing it.